# Swift Codable: dealing with Optimized JSON generating type Mismatch

Tags: swift, codable

I am trying to figure out the correct or best way to deal with APIs that sends out Optimized JSON.
If you have not encontered Optimized JSON as a server respons here is a bit of background, say you have a response for a #color code as #FF2233 the server sends out {"color" : "FF2233"},
But if the code is 223344 then the server sends out {"color" : 223344} cutting out quotes
Same for a single object array it send the object with out the brackets
So far this is what I have in a playground as a test... it works but it seems to me this is not the best way to get around the problem I am trying to solve.

Is there any way to check the type of a value before attempting to decode it so we can at least try to cast it correctly ??

```
struct Test : Codable {

    var a : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a = "a"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do{
            a = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .a)
        }
        catch{
           a = String(describing: try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .a)!)
        }
    }

    init(a: String)
    {
        self.a = a
    }
}

var a = Test(a: "FF2233")
var jd = try? JSONEncoder().encode(a)
var jt = String(bytes: jd!, encoding: .utf8)
jt = "{\"a\":223365}"
jd = jt?.data(using: .utf8)
do{
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: jd!)
    print(res.a!)
} catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're dealing with here is, strictly, broken JSON. Your approach is necessary. It's stupid, but it's only necessary because someone made a stupid decision to send you broken JSON.

You could clean up the code a little by extending `KeyedDecodingContainer` to wrap up these changes in a method called something like `lenientDecode()`. Then you could write something like `a = values.lenientDecode(String.self, forKey:.a)`. You'd still do the same checks, but putting them in a separate method would make it easier to repeat the checks on multiple fields.

Comment: following your answer, I looked for how to extend Codable. found this https://stablekernel.com/understanding-extending-swift-4-codable/ and yes the correct way to get the get to deal with my problem is by extending KeyedDecodingContainer.

Answer (score 1):

I found it so interesting when trying to deal with your data type.

Let's break it down to the underlying type first. At the lowest level, you have `Int` or `String`. Then you have `Single` object or `Array`. And at the highest level you should have a `struct` which can deal with your **Root** object. Basically you need two `enum`s to wrap your `struct`. Let's try:

```
enum IntOrString: Codable {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try .int(container.decode(Int.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                self = try .string(container.decode(String.self))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(IntOrString.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload conflicts with expected type, (Int or String)"))
            }
        }
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .int(let int):
            try container.encode(int)
        case .string(let string):
            try container.encode(string)
        }
    }
}

enum SingleOrArray: Codable {
    case single(IntOrString)
    case array([IntOrString])
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try .single(container.decode(IntOrString.self))
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                self = try .array(container.decode([IntOrString].self))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(SingleOrArray.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload conflicts with expected type"))
            }
        }
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .single(let single):
            try container.encode(single)
        case .array(let array):
            try container.encode(array)
        }
    }
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let color: SingleOrArray
}
```

**Decoding Process**:

```
let jsonData = """
{
 "color":["FF2233", "FF2234", "FF2235"]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
    //print(response)    //["FF2233", "FF2234", "FF2235"]

    // If you want to get underlying elements from this structure, you might do something like below
    // This is your single object
    if case .single(let single) = response.color {
        // Every single object may be an Int or a String
        if case .int(let int) = single {
            print(int)
        }
        if case .string(let string) = single {
            print(string)
        }
    }

    // This is your array
    if case .array(let array) = response.color {
        array.forEach({ (element) in
            // Each element of your array may be an Int or a String
            if case .int(let int) = element {
                print(int)
            }
            if case .string(let string) = element {
                print(string)
            }
        })
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

### The data types that this can handle are:

You can try replacing the value for key `color` in the above JSON with one of these objects

1. **`String`**: `"FF2233"`
2. **`Int`**: `223344`
3. **`[String]`**: `["FF2233", "FF2234", "FF2235"]`
4. **`[Int]`**: `[223344, 223345, 223346]`
5. **Array of String/Int mixed**: `["FF2233", "FF2234", 223344, 223345, "FF2235", 223346]`

> The most surprising fact about this design is that you can parse Mixture of `[Int & String]`

Comment: Hi @nayem, can you tell me how to assign a value to IntOrString variable.

Comment: Yes @arunit21, you can do that simply by `let some = IntOrString.int(7)`.

Comment: Hi @nayem, thank you, me too figured out in my case I did like this,

Comment: user.id = .int((globalUser?.id)!)